# Google Charts: Set exact Date-boundarys in charts (when using FilterSliders)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am showing one or more Time-graphs on a website. I am using a DateRangeSlider, so users can put in exact Times they want to examine. Idealy I want the user to be able to dial in a time, and exactly this time should be shown on the graph. However, the chart will always start with the first avalable datapoint from the filtered set. For Example, I dial in 21-01-2019 as a start date, but the next Datapoint is only at 24-01-2019, then the chart will also start on that later date. For my ussecase it would be better if the chart stays empty until the first datapoint, but really start at 21-01-2019. Even better would be to take the first datapoint that is outside the filtered set, and still show a line between the last point outsider of the set and the first point inside.

Here is the code i am using so far:

```js
var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(chartSliderPos);

var rangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'DateRangeFilter',
    'containerId': chartSliderPos,
    'options': {
    'filterColumnLabel': 'Time',
    'ui': {
        'step': 'hour'
        }
    }
});

// Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn("date", "Time");
data.addColumn("number", "Value");
data.addRows(resultArray);

// Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'SteppedAreaChart',
    'containerId': pos,
    'options': {
        'width': 750,
        'height': 300,
        'explorer': {},
        'legend': 'none'
    }
});
dashboard.bind(rangeSlider, chart);

//callback for slider manipulation 
chartsArray.push( function(a, b) {
    rangeSlider.setState({'lowValue': a, 'highValue': b});
    rangeSlider.draw();
});

dashboard.draw(data);
```

[image: Actual Chart]
As you can see, the range-slider has another date dialed in than the chart is showing, because the next datapoint is only avalable much later.

EDIT: 
By looking through the examples from Google, I found one example where the Range slider does pretty much what I want. However, I dont need the Annotation Chart, and I dont know what makes this work in this example. 
Example: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set a specific start and end date on the chart by using the `hAxis.viewWindow` option.

```
  hAxis: {
    format: 'yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss',
    viewWindow: {
      min: new Date(2019, 3, 1),
      max: new Date(2019, 3, 30)
    }
  }
```

however, the range filter will only allow the min and max values from the data.

instead, you could use your own filter to dial in the dates.

here, the jquery ui slider is used...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var resultArray = [
    [new Date(2019, 3, 18), 555],
    [new Date(2019, 3, 19), 415],
    [new Date(2019, 3, 20), 210],
    [new Date(2019, 3, 21), 210],
    [new Date(2019, 3, 22), 210],
  ];
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Time');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
  data.addRows(resultArray);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'SteppedAreaChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      chartArea: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        top: 24,
        left: 72,
        right: 72,
        bottom: 72
      },
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      explorer: {},
      legend: 'none',
      hAxis: {
        format: 'yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss',
        viewWindow: {
          min: new Date(2019, 3, 1),
          max: new Date(2019, 3, 30)
        }
      }
    }
  });
  chart.draw();

  var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: chart.getOption('hAxis.format')
  });

  $('#date-min').html(formatDate.formatValue(chart.getOption('hAxis.viewWindow.min')));
  $('#date-max').html(formatDate.formatValue(chart.getOption('hAxis.viewWindow.max')));

  $('.slider > div').slider({
    range: true,
    min: chart.getOption('hAxis.viewWindow.min').getTime(),
    max: chart.getOption('hAxis.viewWindow.max').getTime(),
    values: [
      chart.getOption('hAxis.viewWindow.min').getTime(),
      chart.getOption('hAxis.viewWindow.max').getTime()
    ],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      chart.setOption('hAxis.viewWindow.min', new Date(ui.values[0]));
      chart.setOption('hAxis.viewWindow.max', new Date(ui.values[1]));
      $('#date-min').html(formatDate.formatValue(new Date(ui.values[0])));
      $('#date-max').html(formatDate.formatValue(new Date(ui.values[1])));
      chart.draw();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
label {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.chart {
  height: 300px;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 16px;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="chart" id="chart_div"></div>
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <label id="date-min">19/04/01</label>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell slider">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <label id="date-max">19/04/30</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: AMAZING! This really helps me so much!